# Selection of recurrence rules of recurring appointments

Tags: sql

I've got appointments with 3 recurrence types: 1 = master appointment, 2 = regular appointment and 3 = exception. Every recurring appointment has a foreign key value which references the primary key of a recurrence rule table. It might be that the master has been deleted and it might be that only one appointment from the recurring sequence of appointments with a specific rule is left.

I want to select all distinct rows from the appointment relation/table where the foreign key to the primary key of the rule-table is not null (and I need to select all columns of the found rows). Furthermore I need a query which is executable in most relational databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS-SQL, Derby...).

I basically want to select exactly one appointment for each recurrence rule which references this rule, the first one with the "lowest" start date.

Probably it's as simple as SELECT DISTINCT RECRULE, * FROM APPOINTMENTS but I'm not sure if this is valid SQL.

kind regards
Johannes

Comment: Sample data and desired results help to clarify most questions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the rules in the reference table that are being used.  If so:

```
select r.*
from recurrent r
where exists (select 1
              from appointments a
              where a.recurrentid = r.recurrentid
             );
```

This is standard SQL and should work in all databases.

Comment: I think it's another SELECT-statement wrapped around as I want the appointments... SELECT * FROM appointments a where a.recurrentid IN (your query).